# Connecting database to iPhone application

Tags: php, iphone

I have a database created using phpMyAdmin. I need to connect the database to my iphone application to retrieve certain data but i do not know which type of web services i should use and how i should connect them together.

Do anyone know how to connect the database to the iphone application?
Is there any websites which i can follow?
I would greatly appreciated your help !

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app).

Once you are done writing your APIs, You can consume the same in iPhone taking hint from [here](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the database file to your project just by dragging it to the Resources folder in your project navigator. Make sure you add it to the required targets when you are prompted. You can then use SQLite library to read/write the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the database file to your project just by dragging it to the Resources folder in your project navigator. Make sure you add it to the required targets when you are prompted.

Use this code to Load your sqlite file

```
-(void) getdatabasePath
 {

  NSString *databaseName =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"Database.sqlite"];

//Get the path to the Document and append the databaseName
NSArray  *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,       NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documetsDir  = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath    = [[documetsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName] retain];

// Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
if(success) return;

// If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem
NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
   }
```